# How to add a Logical Volume (LV) for /var/tmp?

Tags: filesystems, partition, lvm

I've got one physical volume and one volume group:

```
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt
VG Name ced-vg
```

I've got five logical volumes:

```
/dev/ced-vg/root
/dev/ced-vg/var
/dev/ced-vg/swap_1
/dev/ced-vg/tmp
/dev/ced-vg/home
```

I want to add a sixth logical volume on that same, unique, physical volume (I'm not adding any new SSD), which could maybe look like this:

```
/dev/ced-vg/vartmp   (I don't know if the name is correct)
```

Which I'll then use for */var/tmp/* to have its own logical volume.

I don't know how to create that. I don't understand if these logical volumes were created, once, when the OS was installed or if they're (re-)created at each boot, for example.

Is it as simple as just adding an entry for */var/tmp* in */etc/fstab*?

Or do I need to first "create", once, the new logical volume and only then add the entry to */etc/fstab*?  Or something else?

Do I need to manually create a filesystem for that new */var/tmp* I plan to add? Or shall this be done automatically?

P.S: This is on Debian but I take it the procedure is similar on many distros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new logical volume of size 32GB with name "vartmp" using

```
lvcreate -L 32G -n vartmp ced-vg
```

That's everything about this that's LVM-specific! Then you can format it using your favorite file system, e.g.

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/ced-vg/vartmp
```

and add it to your /etc/fstab, so that it gets picked up on next boot, for example

```
/dev/ced-vg/vartmp /var/tmp   xfs   noatime
```

You might want to check the free space of your volume group first, using `vgdisplay`.

Comment: Looks like the LV should be mounted to a created directory like some of the existing LV's are. Perhaps a mkdir and mount would complete this answer?

Comment: @sseLtaH not necessary. /var/tmp already exists, and manual mounting shouldn't be necessary (or even done for that matter).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: thanks a lot, I had enough room left and it worked fine!